# boost::asio::deadline_timer binding to a polymorphic socket class pointer

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

My scheme is (more or less) the following:

`asio_socket` is the abc with a single pure virtual method:

```
virtual void schedule(
                      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query &,
                      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver &,
                      boost::asio::io_service &
                     ) = 0;
```

Another class `asio_socket_http` inherits from it, and also inherits from another `asio_helper`. Another class `asio_socket_https` also follows the same scheme.

The `asio_socket_http` implements the asio_async handlers, for an http connection.

Other classes (which define specific URI/URL-related operations) inherit either from `asio_socket_http` or `asio_socket_https`.

There exists a job scheduler:

```
void run_job(const std::shared_ptr<asio_socket> job);
```

Internally all it does is:

```
void run_job(const std::shared_ptr<asio_socket> job)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    job->schedule(query_, resolver, io);
    io.run();
}
```

I want to add a deadline timer, which will deal with the async nature of asio:

```
void run_job(const std::shared_ptr<asio_socket> job)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(3)); 
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&asio_socket::schedule, *job));
    // I also have to bind the 3 params: query_, resolver, io
    io.run();
}
```

Doing so, I get `template argument deduction/substitution failed:`
and the actual error is:

`‘void (rapp::cloud::asio_socket::*)(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::query&, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver&, boost::asio::io_service&) {aka void (rapp::cloud::asio_socket::*)(boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_query<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::io_service&)}’ is not derived from ‘boost::type<R>’
     timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&asio_socket::schedule, *job));`

How can I bind the method `schedule` of the (polymorphic) shared pointer `job`, and also bind the parameters?
Trying:

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&asio_socket::schedule, *job, _1, _2, _3)(&query_, &resolver, &io))
```

Complains about passing 5 arguments whilst the candidate expects 2 arguments.
My guess is that `timer.async_wait` wants to bind a method to an object?

1. How can I bind correctly the async timer to the schedule operation?
2. Do I need to do nested binding, once for the async timer and once for the scheduled job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass references into `bind` you need to pass them as a `reference_wapper<>`, which you can make with `boost::ref(x)` or `boost::cref(x)`.

If you don't, the `bind` call will try to copy them, which of course can't work for a non-copyable `asio` object.

Something like this should work:

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&asio_socket::schedule, 
                job,  // should bind to a shared_ptr just fine 
                boost::ref(query_),
                boost:;ref(resolver),
                boost::ref(io),
                boost::placeholders::_1);
```

schedule will need the following signature:

```
(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query &,
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver &,
 boost::asio::io_service &,
 const boost::system::error_code& ec)
```

because async_wait demands that its handler is able to accept an error code argument as its 'first' unbound argument.

This is why you have to specify boost::placeholders::_1 - to marshal the 'first' argument in the binder (created by bind) to the fourth argument of your class's handler method.

Comment: many thanks for the help. I've tried with `boost::ref` but I got `error: invalid use of non-static member function`. So now I am trying by using `boost::mem_fn` and `boost::ref`. I am still confused though, don't I need to also bind the parameters of the method `schedule`?

Comment: @Ælex updated answer. hope that makes sense. if not, have a look at the examples in the asio documentation.

Comment: actually that worked! Tons of thanks! I'm still a bit perplexed, but that makes sense. I'm surprised it works with `std::shared_ptr`. One last question, the placeholder is for the `job` object pointer, and not for the references to the arguments?

Comment: @Ælex the placeholder is for the argument that async_wait will supply when it calls your handler. It expects to call a handler with the signature f(const error_code& ec). The placeholder allows it to send you that one argument and you then bind that placeholder into the 4th argument of your handler method. std::bind for a member function will bind to pointer, shared_ptr and (from memory) a reference wrapper. There are multiple overloads of bind in order to cater for most use cases (this is true of std::bind also, which incidentally can also be used to construct an asio handler).